# Why is my variable inside a function not defined even if it's global?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, global-variables

So I made a function to open sites:

```
import webbrowser

def go_to_url(link):
    
    global YT, Reddit, SO
    YT = 'youtube.com'
    Reddit = 'reddit.com'
    SO = 'stackoverflow.com'
    webbrowser.open(link)

go_to_url(YT)
```

No syntax error when running, but returns result:

***NameError: name 'YT' is not defined***

Later I tried to define the variables outside the function and it worked:

```
import webbrowser

def go_to_url(link):
   webbrowser.open(link)

YT = 'youtube.com'
Reddit = 'reddit.com'
SO = 'stackoverflow.com'

go_to_url(YT)
```

I just don't understand **why can't I define it inside my function, even if they are global** anyway. Please explain it to me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you have here is that the variable isn't defined until you actually run the function, and so `YT` doesn't exist at the time you're trying to make the call. As an example:

```
In [144]: def make_vars():
     ...:     global hello
     ...:     hello = "world"
     ...:

In [145]: print(hello)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-1cd80308eb4c> in <module>
----> 1 print(hello)

NameError: name 'hello' is not defined

In [146]: make_vars()

In [147]: print(hello)
world
```

Comment: Ahh I get it now. Thanks a lot !